# trying to write string to a txt file in swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Save data to file
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Test", ofType: "txt")
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let text = "write this\n and this"

        do {
            try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to put the text into the txt file which I already put in the project folder, but after running the code, the Test.txt file is still empty.

Comment: An app's resource bundle is read-only.

Comment: how do I fix it?

Comment: Write the file to a writable folder in your app's sandbox.

Comment: I have put the test.txt file in my project already, isn't it writable?

Comment: You can not write to the read-only bundle resources (which contained inside your app), you can write to `Application Support` instead.
#seemore: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Where is my app's sandbox? I can't find it, there is only a folder called writetest.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the documentation link above. There are a couple of places you can write files, this is just one of them:

```
        let userDocumentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let path = userDocumentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Test.txt")
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let text = "write this\n and this"

        do {
            try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
```

Comment: So I need to create another function? It said value of type'String'  has no member 'stringbyAppendingPathComponet'

Comment: No. Just replace your lines with these. The important part is getting the path.

Comment: It isn't "stringbyAppendingPathComponent" it's: "stringByAppendingPathComponent". What version of Swift are you using? I'm using 3.2

Comment: 3.2 also ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Is there a way I can see this file in my laptop?

Comment: When I copy the path into the console , it said access denied.

Comment: That's right. You can copy files from the simulator, but the file system on the actual device is protected.